# Is Scalatra autoreload when the code changed?

Tags: scala, scalatra

Is [scalatra](http://www.scalatra.org) (Scala server side framework) auto-refresh when one of our source code changed (just like PHP)?

or if they are not, is there any Scala server side framework that able to do that (edit code, then test on the browser, without needing to restart the scala/server program)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use follow command to run scalatra.

> ### $ ./sbt
>
> ### container:start
>
> ### ~ ;copy-resources;aux-compile

for more details please visit [this](http://scalatra.org/2.2/getting-started/first-project.html#toc_91)

Answer (score 1):

try ~jetty:start in sbt shell.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30071391)